# Discord.js check if bot is capable of sending embeds into a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how to check if my bot has permission to send messages and include embeds into a specific channel.

I have found the following code that returns a boolean if a specific member has a permission in a specific channel. but I'm unsure how to perform the same action for the bot itself.

```
message.member.permissionIn('channel_id').hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES');
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the other answers explain how the get the `GuildMember` object, so I'll try explaining it. All you need to do is get the `GuildMember` from your `client`. To do this, use `client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id).members.me` to your the bot's `GuildMember`, then from there you can use the same code. Try this:

```
client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id).members.me.permissionsIn(channel_id).has('SEND_MESSAGES')
```

where `guild_id` is the server ID and `channel_id` is the channel ID.

Alternatively, if you already have the `Message` object, then you can just the the `Guild` from there. Like this:

```
message.guild.members.me.permissionsIn(channel_id).has('SEND_MESSAGES')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the GuildMember has permission.

```
[Guild].me.permissionsIn('channel_id').has('SEND_MESSAGES')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Discord.JS v14, you can do the following:

```
const { PermissionFlagsBits } = require("discord.js");

// Check for permissions
if (!channel.permissionsFor(interaction.guild.members.me).has(PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages)) {
    // No permissions!
}
```

In which `channel` is your channel object